# static cast or c style cast

Tags: c++, memory

I am trying to implement memchr() function . my code must return a void * , so if we find the character we can change it . the problem is here . I have two approaches one approach is c_style .

```
void *memChr(const void *s1, int c, size_type n)
{
    const char *p = (const char *)s1;

    while (n--)
    if (*p++== (char)c)
        return (void *)--p;

        return 0;
}
```

these approach uses c-style cast , here we send s1 as const , which is proper cause we don't want any change , and then we return p as a non const pointer to void which is again proper . any way this is old , and I want a more c++ approach. like this :

```
void *memChr( void *s1, int c, int n)
{
    char *p = static_cast< char *>(s1);

    while (n--)
    if (*p++ == static_cast<char>(c))
        return static_cast<void *>(p);

    return 0;
}
```

my problem with these code is this : I cant cast a const pointer to a non const pointer .static_cast is safer than c style cast , but It makes me to use non const parameter which it is not appropriate . with standard memchr() parameters ,there is no way to be implemented with static_cast .
so which approach is better? I have just finished c++ tutorials , and I am trying to learn good coding , but I am a little confused .

Comment: What if `s1` originally points to const data? That is, regardless of which style you use, as long as you want to return a non-const pointer, you should declare `s1` as non-const pointer. Then, you don't need the `const_cast`. For clarity, I would recommend the c++ style cast.

Comment: It is bad practice to remove `const` qualifier from input. If you want to modify data at returned pointer, then take non-const as input. Or better to return const pointer and force caller to remove `const` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use const_cast to cast from const to non-const pointer:

```
void *memChr( const char *s1, int c, int n)
{
    char *p = const_cast< char *>(s1);

    while (n--)
    if (*p++ == static_cast<char>(c))
        return static_cast<void *>(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this answer should at least go with a disclaimer that, while this works, it is a very bad practice to take const pointer as a function argument, and then cast the const-ness away inside that function.

Comment: Agree with @void_ptr . Deconsting `const` data can lead to seriously nasty and unpredictable results. If a function is going to modify a parameter it makes absolutely no sense to declare the parameter `const`. This is lying to the function's callers, telling them their data will not be modified, then stabbing them in the back. Really uncool.